# how to read local.settings.json configuration in index.js file

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I have NodeJS azure function and have some variable sets in  `local.settings.json` file,

```
"NEO4J_URI": "bolt://localhost:7687",
"NEO4J_USER": "sa",
"NEO4J_PASSWORD": "Password1",
```

I want to read these variables in `index.js` file to replace below hard coding, how to read it?

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
"bolt://localhost:7687",
 neo4j.auth.basic("sa", "Password1")
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In `index.js`, You need to call the `process.env` method to access the application settings defined from `local.settings.json` as environment variables as you can see the below workaround:**

[image: workaround]

**Reference:** [Access local.settings.json application settings from Azure Functions - JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export,v2-v3-v4-done,v2,v2-log-custom-telemetry,v2-accessing-request-and-response,windows-setting-the-node-version#environment-variables)

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for sharing documentation!